# Mongoose: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value “me” at path “_id”

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, express, mongoose

I know there are a lot of version of this question, but I couldn't find anything helping me.

```
function isAuthenticated() {
  return compose()
    // Validate jwt
    .use(function (req, res, next) {
      // allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
      if (req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
        req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token;
      }
      validateJwt(req, res, next);
    })
    // Attach user to request
    .use(function (req, res, next) {
      User.findById(req.user._id, function (err, user) {
        console.log(next);
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          return res.send(401);
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
      });
    });
}
```

Here is the error :

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "me" at path "_id"
    at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\node_modules\mongoose\lib\
schema\objectid.js:116:13)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\node_modules\mongo
ose\lib\schema\objectid.js:165:17)
    at Query.cast (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\node_modules\mongoose\lib\que
ry.js:2317:32)
    at Query.findOne (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\node_modules\mongoose\lib\
query.js:1118:10)
    at Function.findOne (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\node_modules\mongoose\l
ib\model.js:1049:13)
    at Function.findById (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\node_modules\mongoose\
lib\model.js:986:15)
    at Object.exports.show [as handle] (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\server\a
pi\user.js:43:8)
    at next_layer (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\node_modules\express\lib\rout
er\route.js:103:13)
    at next (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\node_modules\composable-middleware\
lib\composable-middleware.js:40:9)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Benoit\Desktop\Gakusei\server\auth\auth.ser
vice.js:37:9)
```

I'm adapting some of Yeoman boilerplate auth code and I didn't touch this part. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

for completness, here my api for 'me'

```
exports.me = function (req, res, next) {
  var userId = req.user._id;
  User.findOne({
    _id: userId
  }, '-salt -hashedPassword', function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json(401);
    }
    res.json(user);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a object with `findOne` by querying _id to be equal to 'me'. Mongoose is attempt to convert the string 'me' to an ObjectId but fails. I can't tell from the traceback if it's your `me` function which is the issue (that's the only place where findOne is used in the code you have provided), but you could try to change the function call to `User.findById(userId, ...)` instead. Don't see why userId is equal to 'me' however or if that would help any at all. Hope this gave you some direction at least. Add a comment if you still have problems.

Comment: @Benoit did this help  any?

Answer (score 1):

it is old question but since i got the same issue and resolved the issue, I want to post for a future reference.

you get this error because you put

```
router.get("/:id", controller code)
```

before

```
router.get("/me", controller code)
```

you should always put specific routes before the generic ones.