# When populating in mongoose CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "11" at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have inserted data in MongoDB via `--jsonArray` command. Where my primary key is already exists so I replaced `my key` with `_id` and then inserted. So `_id` is not automatically generated by the mongoDB.

When I am trying to populate the data I'm getting below error.

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "11" at path "_id"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "11" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 11,
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined }
```

Please some one help me to fix this issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795430/mongoose-casterror-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-me-at-path-id try solving from this link. Seems `"11"` is not an `ObjectId`.

Comment: I am actually populating the code. **Even using the same it is generating the same error.** @titi23